# Check if file exists in Sharepoint and save

Tags: vba, sharepoint

I need to check if a file exists on Sharepoint. If no, I want to save it: if it already exists, I want to save a copy of it

```
Sub save() 
   Dim newFile as string, fName as string, path as string

   fName = Sheets(“Universe”).Cells(2,2).Value
   newFile = fName & Format$(Date, “dd-mm-yyyy”)
   path = “SharePoint URL”

   If Len(Dir(path & newFile & “.xlsm”) = 0 Then 
      ActiveWprkbook.SaveAs Filename := path & newFile &        “.xlsm”, 
      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled,   CreateBackup:= False
   Else
      ActiveWprkbook.SaveAs Filename := path & newFile & “Copy” & “.xlsm”, 
      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:= False
   End If 
End sub
```

The first time the file is successfully saved; however, it always finds the If condition to be true and proceeds to overwrite the existing file.

How do I change the code such that it recognises when a file has been created and so makes of copy of it?

Comment: What is the value of Cells(2,2) ? Can you please paste it ?

Comment: Please give a try to my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57374280/11167163) this should work, If it doesn't please give me feedbacks so I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this :

An example of path : "`Z:Documents\Reports\2013\"` would be `"\\sharepoint\Documents\Reports\2013\"`

```
 Sub save()
    Dim newFile As String, fName As String, path As String
    fName = Sheets(“Universe”).Cells(2, 2).Value
    newFile = fName & Format$(Date, “dd - mm - yyyy”)
    path = “SharePoint URL”

     myWorkbookBasePath = path & newFile & “.xlsm”

 If Dir(myWorkbookBasePath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myWorkbookBasePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
 Else:
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myWorkbookBasePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
 End If

End Sub
```

**Note :**

1. Make sure that your path end with a `\`
2. I Think `ActiveWprkbook` should be `ActiveWorkbook`